# Problems compiling file on School's Unix System

Tags: java, unix

**COMPLETE EDIT BUT SIMILAR PROBLEM**

What's the best software/plugin to enable FTP on Eclipse? I'm using FileZilla, but is there something better/easier?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do with gamedata.txt? Put it in the .jar? You'll have to do that as a separate step. Easier way than copying / pasting - depends on the setup you've got. Can you SCP files in e.g. using pscp from the PuTTY download? You may even be able to copy in the compiled .jars.

Comment: I don't understand why u ask this question?  I thought one of the selling points of JAVA is crossplatform compatibility.  Compile it at home and scp the jar file.  R u a student who needs to do this 2 submit homework? (If so ask ur prof how 2 submit assignments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling `javac` to compile `gamedata.txt` and it is reporting an error that it cannot compile this file.

I'd highly suggest using a tool like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to script your compilation/packaging/etc so you don't have to worry about typing in arguments on the command line.

Comment: I will. But for now, how do I fix this?

Comment: Definitely leave out `gamedata.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples in the [`javac`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#examples) synopsis.

Edit: Updated link to Solaris examples, which are similar to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the -J command line argument is not meant to be literally passed as `-J<flag>`. Taken directly from the javac man page (you can view the exact same thing by typing `man javac` into the shell):

```
-Joption
              Pass option to the java launcher called by javac.  For  example,
              -J-Xms48m  sets  the startup memory to 48 megabytes. Although it
              does not begin with -X, it is not a `standard option' of  javac.
              It is a common convention for -J to pass options to the underly-
              ing VM executing applications written in Java.
```

Really, if you want to make this an executable, you can just use the tools that exist in Eclipse to make an executable. Using the command-line javac adds an extra level of complexity that is unnecessary, and that Eclipse is specifically designed to remove.

In eclipse, you can (I think) use *File->Export->Java->Executable JAR File* to make your project into an executable JAR that any computer with the Java Virtual Machine can run. That way, your project will work on both your computer and the Unix system at your school. You may have to add gameData.txt manually to the JAR or include it separately in the package, not sure how Eclipse does that type of thing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can only compile .java files.  If you remove the .txt file from the list of files to compile, it should work fine.  If you want to compile all the files in a directory, you can simply use `javac *.java`

Comment: Still doesn't work. The problem is that I need to transport the gameData.txt file from my computer to my account. Any ideas how I can do that? Does that require ftp?